# installing istio on kubernetes which is hosted on azure

Tags: azure, kubernetes, istio

I'm newbie in Istio and trying to install it on Kubernetes cluster poc which is hosted on Azure. It is not AKS. I have 2 workers and 2 controller nodes. My kubernetes cluster is working fine. I tried ingress controllers also.  But during installation of istio(https://istio.io/docs/setup/getting-started/) Istio Ingress, egress pods are not running and I see below error in the logs.

```
    warning envoy config    [bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/external/envoy/source/common/config/_virtual_includes/grpc_stream_lib/common/config/grpc_stream.h:92] StreamAggregatedResources gRPC config stream closed: 14, no healthy upstream


    warning envoy config    [bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/external/envoy/source/common/config/_virtual_includes/grpc_stream_lib/common/config/grpc_stream.h:92] StreamAggregatedResources gRPC config stream closed: 14, upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: connection failure

    info    grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {istiod.istio-system.svc:15012  <nil> 0 <nil>}. Err: connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 10.32.0.153:15012: i/o timeout". Reconnecting...

    info    Subchannel Connectivity change to TRANSIENT_FAILURE

    info    pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc0003d3ac0, {TRANSIENT_FAILURE connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 10.32.0.153:15012: i/o timeout"}

    info    Channel Connectivity change to TRANSIENT_FAILURE
     error   citadelclient   Failed to create certificate: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 10.32.0.153:15012: i/o timeout"
```

Am I missing any permissions/policies at azure level? In tried to search articles but didn't find solution?  Could somebody help me in installing it?

thanks,
Santosh

Comment: How have you installed istio?

Comment: I followed https://istio.io/docs/setup/getting-started/ procedure

Comment: did you get installation complete? have no idea then. Uninstall it (`istioctl manifest generate --set profile=demo | kubectl delete -f-`), and install it with the same command, but `kubectl create -f-`. Try the create command two times.

Comment: All these errors and warning are regarding network connectivity. How did You install K8s cluster? Is Your CNI pluggin up and running? Also did You complete [Azure](https://istio.io/docs/setup/platform-setup/azure/) platform specific tasks?

Comment: @suren, i did your method and now i get "MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "ingressgateway-certs" : failed to sync secret cache: timed out waiting for the condition"  Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[istio-token istiod-ca-cert], unattached volumes=[ingressgateway-certs ingressgatewaysdsudspath istio-ingressgateway-service-account-token-p7r5m config-volume podinfo istio-envoy istio-token istiod-ca-cert ingressgateway-ca-certs]: timed out waiting for the condition  errors. I think is is something related to networking or nsg?

Comment: @PiotrMalec, since I have installed k8s cluster separately and document which you provided is more focused on AKS or creating new k8s cluster. correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: it is not aks. he is installing on VMs. @santosh.a have you run the command twice?

Comment: yes I did run command twice.

Comment: i see this error in istod pod: kubelet, worker-1  MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "istio-token" : failed to fetch token: the API server does not have TokenRequest endpoints enabled.

Comment: oh. then I would say your cluster is not actually properly configured. enable that feature gate on api-server: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/feature-gates/

Comment: Add the k8s cluster deployment method and versions of istio and k8s. Also check if all k8s system pods are running.

Comment: @PiotrMalec, i installed k8s using the 'hard-way' by searching on internet. https://github.com/ivanfioravanti/kubernetes-the-hard-way-on-azure/ . 

k8s version is : 1.17, Istio version is 1.6.0 . All pods on k8s are running.

Answer (score 0):

Try temporarily opening all ports to allow the installation process to complete. Then you may need to check which ports Istio depends on for validating GRPC/Webhooks and other services.

There may be other solutions but this worked for me.

Comment: I also opened all ports but failing with same error